# Deep learning for face detection in mobile device

Tags: mobile, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning

I want to create a face detection mobile app and I want to do it with a regular Deep Learning(Convolutional Network). I will train it with my computer and use trained data in the mobile app.

My question is that: can I get very fast computation in the regulat phone like iPhone? I need it be very fast and under 1 sec can detect a face in the video. Is it possible on a mobile device? or this kind of task need more powerful hardware?

I know training phase must be in a powerful computer but I mean production phase in a mobile device.

for example, if I put my phone in a street, It can detect all peoples face with the same deep network in training phase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but not with standard CNN architectures, some changes are needed:

- One approach is CNNs with binary weights, so evaluating the CNN can just be done with bit operations. There are many publications about this, like [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830), [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05279) or [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.00363). I have seen an implementation of YOLO  with binary weights running in real-time on an iPhone, so it is definitely possible.
- A second approach is to reduce the number of parameters of the neural network, for example if you train a network with 5000 weights and gets detection performance that is close to what you want, then this network might run in real-time. But this is harder.
- Third approach is just to optimize the neural network architecture to minimize parameters, and combine it with a very optimized implementation. There are algorithms to speedup convolution operations, such as [L-CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06473), or the ones implemented by cuDNN.

A very good related resource are the presentation and papers from the [The 1st International Workshop on Efficient Methods for Deep Neural Networks](http://allenai.org/plato/emdnn/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot